# ksqldb creating table from a stream which contains values, is initialized with no values at all. only new values inserted to the table

Tags: ksqldb

I am new to ksqldb and I'm trying to understand this phenomenon.

I configured this first: `SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';`

I created this stream:

```sql
CREATE STREAM customers WITH (
    kafka_topic = 'postgres.public.customers',
    value_format = 'avro'
);
```

values in the stream:

```
ksql> select * from customers;
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|ID                          |NAME                        |AGE                         |__DELETED                   |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|5                           |fred                        |34                          |false                       |
|7                           |sue                         |25                          |false                       |
|2                           |bill                        |51                          |false                       |
```

I created the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers_by_key AS
    SELECT id,
           latest_by_offset(name) AS name,
           latest_by_offset(age) AS age
    FROM customers
    GROUP BY id
    EMIT CHANGES;
```

But the table is empty:

```
ksql> select * from customers_by_key;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|ID                                    |NAME                                  |AGE                                   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

It is important to mention that the customers_by_key topic is also empty of messages.

But if I insert a new value to `customers` stream, here I inserted new record of 'joe':

```
ksql> select * from customers;
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|ID                          |NAME                        |AGE                         |__DELETED                   |
+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|5                           |fred                        |34                          |false                       |
|7                           |sue                         |25                          |false                       |
|2                           |bill                        |51                          |false                       |
|3                           |joe                         |20                          |false                       |
```

The record of 'joe' does appear in the `customers_by_key` tabel:

```
ksql> select * from customers_by_key;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|ID                                    |NAME                                  |AGE                                   |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|3                                     |joe                                   |20                                    |
```

I expect that the table will contain values which are already exists in the stream at the time of the table creation and not only new values inserted after creating the table. Maybe I have missing configuration or I did not understand the concept of a table correctly in ksqldb.